# PECL_HTTP is installed, but does not work

Tags: php, pear, pecl, lampp

I have installed `pecl_http`, but when I try to use it, I get an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function http_get() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/tes_http.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/tes_http.php on line 3

This is my `php.ini` configuration:

```
extension="propro.so"
extension="http.so"
extension="raphf.so"
[PHP]

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Please help me to figure out why the function is not available.

Comment: If you're not yet you have to enable`;extension=php_http.dll` in your `php.ini` file. Simply remove semicolons and after that restart your Apache Server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current version of `http` extension (the *[package](https://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http) name* is `pecl_http`) doesn't provide `http_get()` function. This function has been removed in version 2.0.0 (right after version 1.7.6). You can see it by running the following commands in terminal:

```
git clone https://github.com/m6w6/ext-http.git
cd ext-http
git diff RELEASE_1_7_6 RELEASE_2_0_0
```

Although it is not mentioned explicitly in the [changelog](https://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=pecl_http), the procedural style is completely replaced with OOP style in the second version.

The [documentation on PHP's official site](http://php.net/manual/fa/function.http-get.php) is obsolete. Extension's author hosted the new version on [his own site](https://mdref.m6w6.name/http). I wouldn't blame him much, as the link for documentation on the [PECL site](https://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http) points to the right place. Undoubtedly, he should remove the old documentation from `php.net/manual`, or at least update it.

The new way to perform HTTP GET requests implies the use of `http\Client\Request` class:

```
$request = new http\Client\Request("GET",
  "http://example.com",
  ["User-Agent"=>"MyAgent/0.1"]
);
$request->setOptions(["timeout" => 1]);

$client = new http\Client;
$client->enqueue($request)->send();

$response = $client->getResponse();
```

**Regarding the setup**

You should load the dependencies *before* `http.so` as it is recommended in the [documentation](https://mdref.m6w6.name/http#PHP.extensions:):

```
; obligatory deps
extension = raphf.so
extension = propro.so

; if shared deps were enabled
extension = hash.so
extension = iconv.so
extension = json.so

; finally load pecl/http
extension = http.so
```

Comment: i have been using your script but i still got an error 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'http\Client\Request' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/tes_http.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/tes_http.php on line 3

Comment: @Herdy, what is the output for `var_dump(extension_loaded('http'));`? Is the extension present in the output of `phpinfo();`?

Comment: yeah i got an output like this bool(false)
do you know how to solve this.? i'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, PHP 7 and LAMPP @Ruslan

Comment: @Herdy, load the dependencies _before_ `http.so` as it is recommended in [the docs](https://mdref.m6w6.name/http#PHP.extensions:)