# PHP HTTP extension on Docker alpine image

Tags: php, docker, composer-php, alpine-linux

I am trying to install/enable the PHP http extension on my PHP alpine image.

My `composer.json` file for my application contains `"ext-http": "*"`, hence my goal.

My Dockerfile (relevant portions) is as follows:

```
# PHP-FPM Base Image
FROM php:7.2.26-fpm-alpine

# Install PHP extensions
RUN apk add --update --virtual .build-deps autoconf g++ make zlib-dev curl-dev \
  && pecl install raphf propro \
  && docker-php-ext-enable raphf propro \
  && pecl install pecl_http \
  && echo -e "extension=raphf.so\nextension=propro.so\nextension=http.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-http.ini \
  && rm -rf /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-raphf.ini \
  && rm -rf /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-propro.ini \
  && apk del .build-deps \
  && rm -rf /tmp/*
```

However when running `composer update`, I get the following warning:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'http.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/http.so (Error relocating /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/http.so: uidna_IDNToASCII: symbol not found), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/http.so.so (Error loading shared library /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/http.so.so: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

After which, the `composer update` command fails:

```
The requested PHP extension ext-http * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's http extension.
```

The `http.so.so` part of the warning gives me pause, making me think the file is being looked for in an incorrect location.

My reference is the following Dockerfile: https://hub.docker.com/r/realpaul/docker-php/dockerfile

Can someone please help me debug this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A part of that error message reads:

> http.so: uidna_IDNToASCII: symbol not found

According to [PECL_HTTP is installed, but does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40500051/pecl-http-is-installed-but-does-not-work), this error message points to `iconv.so` not being available. Please try to enable that also through echo'ing to `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-http.ini`.

Additionally, if you assume that `http.so` is not placed at the position PHP is expecting, you should try to start a bash in your running container to see whether that file is there or not. But as that file throws an error, you can assume it's there