# How to add ext-http in Dockerfile

Tags: php, linux, docker, docker-compose, alpine-linux

i have the following simple dockerfile to add php from alpine,

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring tokenizer mysqli pdo_mysql


COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN composer install
```

and while running `composer install` it complains with this message `- The requested PHP extension ext-http * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's http extension.`

i tried to see if i can install it using 'docker-php-ext-install' but according to [here](https://gist.github.com/chronon/95911d21928cff786e306c23e7d1d3f3) the extension is not included.

also tried to add `RUN apk add php-http`, i also got the following error message [image]

PS: it works locally on my local linux machine after installing the extension using `sudo apt install php-http`

Comment: Please check this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60108096/php-http-extension-on-docker-alpine-image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you could add a `apk update` before adding packages. However the `php_http` package does not exist in alpine so you need to compile the pecl module.

Using the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60108096/6518606) as an inspiration, I found adding this to your `Dockerfile` works well:

```
RUN apk add --update --virtual .build-deps autoconf g++ make zlib-dev curl-dev libidn2-dev libevent-dev icu-dev libidn-dev 
RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring tokenizer mysqli pdo_mysql json hash iconv

RUN pecl install raphf propro
RUN docker-php-ext-enable raphf propro
RUN pecl install pecl_http
RUN echo -e "extension=raphf.so\nextension=propro.so\nextension=iconv.so\nextension=http.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-http.ini
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-raphf.ini
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-propro.ini
RUN rm -rf /tmp/*
```

Comment: Yes, but I think this could help. Before adding `php-http`, `apk update`